# SQL Azure backup failed - all logins used and now cant connect to the db

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

The automated backup failed leaving a dead database from the backup process and a production database that no one can connect to as it reports all logins are in use  (120)

I cant connect to kill the connections either as on azure sql paas you dont get access to master.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I kill connections to Azure SQL database if I can't access it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844627/how-do-i-kill-connections-to-azure-sql-database-if-i-cant-access-it)

The above link should help you and is as a result of someone having a similar issue to you.  Check out the DAC Admin connection link within it.

Comment: Thanks Steve - will that work even though I can't access master ?

Comment: You don't get access to Master and this article is specific to SQL Azure, so yes.

Comment: I've raised a ticket.. 8hrs sla unfortunatley. I'm able to connect to Master via admin, but then as expected dont have permission to do anything with it. I cant connect to my db via DAC, i get the same error regarding LoginLimits reached. I'm surpised the locked connections don't time out at some point, it will be 24hrs at midnight.

Comment: It does suggest a reset time, so clearly something not correct or different to our assessment.  Be interesting to here if their is something we are missing here.

Comment: UPDATE - woke this morning to find the DB is now back available. Could be the connections timed out after 24 hours , or could be because i failed our system over to a new instance and restored from backup.. This left the original locked db with nothing trying to connect at all. Still disappointing that it could get into a state where you cant rescue the server. This would also seem to negate the point in time restore ability as this can only be done to the same server instance, not another.